# Delete child records if the count exceeds 10

Tags: mysql

I have a parent-child relation for the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)

CREATE TABLE `pageObjects` (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    object TEXT NULL,
    lastChanged TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    fkPageId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)
```

The `pages` have a one:many relation with `pageObjects`.

Whenever the `pageObjects` records connected to a single page exceed 10, all records that are edited furthest in the past and exceeding the 10 must be deleted.

I wanted to do this in a single query, but I can't seem to figure this out...

This is how far I've gotten:

```
DELETE 
FROM pageObjects
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT po.id, po.fkPageId FROM (
        SELECT objects.fkPageId FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as count, fkPageId
            FROM pageObjects
            GROUP BY fkPageId
        ) objects
        WHERE count > 10
    ) AS page
    JOIN pageObjects po 
    ON page.fkPageId = po.fkPageId
    AND po.lastChanged  < (
        SELECT MIN(lastChanged )
        FROM pageObjects
        WHERE fkPageId = po.fkPageId
        GROUP BY fkPageId
        ORDER BY lastChanged  DESC
        LIMIT 10
    )
)
```

Sadly, the LIMIT bit in the bottom sub-query is not working the way I want to, because the MIN() function should be applied AFTER the LIMIT is applied.

So I tried that:

```
DELETE 
FROM pageObjects
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT po.id, po.fkPageId FROM (
        SELECT objects.fkPageId FROM (
            SELECT COUNT(*) as count, fkPageId
            FROM pageObjects
            GROUP BY fkPageId
        ) objects
        WHERE count > 10
    ) AS page
    JOIN pageObjects po 
    ON page.fkPageId = po.fkPageId
    AND po.lastChanged  < (
        SELECT MIN(lastChanged)
        FROM (  
            SELECT lastChanged
            FROM pageObjects
            WHERE fkPageId = po.fkPageId
            GROUP BY fkPageId
            ORDER BY lastChanged DESC
            LIMIT 10
        )
    )
)
```

But this is not possible, because the po.fkPageId is not available in the sub-query of the sub-query.

Is there any way to do this like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite simply by counting the number of later entries for each id:

```
DELETE FROM pageObjects
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM pageObjects po
  WHERE (
    SELECT count(id) 
    FROM pageObjects po2 
    WHERE po2.fkPageId = po.fkPageId
    AND po2.lastChanged > po.lastChanged
  ) > 10
)
```

Check out what the select returns here:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5218f/1/0

Comment: This works great. What you do here is get all records that are older than 10 sibling records, right? Very nice. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Yup, spot on. By deleting all records with more than 10 younger siblings you are inherently left with just the latest 10.